# How do I join all the channels in my weechat layout?

Tags: weechat

Sometimes I need to reboot my linode, which includes my IRC client, weechat, running in tmux.  When I do this, I prefer to save all the buffers that are running and rejoin them.  I was under the impression that:

```
 /layout save
 /save
```

Would store the appropriate information and

```
 /layout apply
```

Would... well apply it.  Unfortunately, while it correctly *places* new channels, it does not in any way rejoin the ones I was connected to before.  I understand that I can manually add a list of channels to autojoin, for each network, but if I have to do that tedious process each time I need to close and reopen weechat... well that would be a drag at the very least.

Any ideas?  I am sure I've done this before.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Okay, after asking around in the freenode #weechat channel a bit I finally got this:

- Download the [autojoin.py](http://www.weechat.org/files/scripts/autojoin.py) script to ~/.weechat/python/autoload
- Run `/python autoload` to load the script
- Run `/autojoin --run` to store the channels to join
- Run `/layout store` to store the order of the channels
- Run `/save` to save your settings to a file

Next time you start weechat and connect to a server the channels you were connected to when you did these steps will be joined for you.

Comment: what version of weechat are you on, as debian stable is *way* behind current, and the wording of your question does not mention using an old version of weechat? Not that it a big deal, but just a dated method/harder.

Comment: Is it that much harder though?  You install the script with wget instead of another command, and you use /python instead of /script.  While I understand that many don't see the benefit of using packaged software, this works for both old *and* new versions.  So why not?

Comment: One of the big things with the `/script` command, is you can keep your scripts up to date with minimal effort; it will tell you that there are new versions, and you can update right from the interactive buffer. No reason to go back to the days of irssi, and update/install by hand ^_-

Comment: Yeah, that's legit.  Although in this case I still think it's overkill, given that the script in question was last updated 5 years ago.

Comment: I'm on Weechat 1.0.1, and I needed to call `/layout store` instead

Comment: This works great until you join a channel requiring authorization with a nickserver, and the client joins the channel before the nickserv can finish authorization.

Answer (score 4):

WeeChat 3.5 (released on 2022-03-27) has introduced a built-in `/autojoin` command.  If you are running version 3.5 or above, the `autojoin.py` script mentioned in Frew's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/743217/1799634) is no longer needed.  The updated steps are as follows:

1. Run `/autojoin apply` to set the currently joined channels in the
   autojoin option.
2. Run `/layout store` to store the order of the channels.
3. Run `/save` to save your settings to a file.

The next time you start WeeChat and connect to a server, the channels you were connected to when you did these steps will be joined for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can [automate the other answer](https://superuser.com/a/743217/137286) such that your buffer layout is saved to disk every hour:

1. Get the [cron.py](https://weechat.org/scripts/source/cron.py.html/) user script:

   - Run `/script` (e.g. in the `weechat.core` buffer)
   - Type `cron`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the buffer which was just opened
   - Select `cron.py` via cursors, type `i` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> for installation.
2. In the `weechat.core` buffer, execute the following command:

   ```
   /cron add 0 1 * * * * core.weechat commands /autojoin --run;/layout store;/save
   ```

   This adds an hourly cron job running the commands the other answer suggested. Note that the commands are separated by `;` without trailing spaces! Execute `/cron help` for more information.
3. Test this by first executing `/cron list`, remembering the number of the cron job you just added (e.g. 001), and then running `/cron exec 001`.